# What's the best way to detect points on an image?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm using optical flow algorithms, and i've tried manually select every 30th pixel in each row and columns, and the GFTTDetector's detect method, but i can't seem to find a proper way to select the real points that are good to be detected. My goal would be to detect a ball's moving in pictures.
I'm currently using emgu cv.

Comment: Sounds like you want a corner or interesting point detector; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision)#Feature_detectors

Comment: Yeah, the GFTTDetector in emgu uses the Shi & Thomasi algorithm, so i've tried it